# TypeError: Bad argument using Node.js fs.read()

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I'm trying to get `fs.read()` to work but running into some issue(s). Here is my `fread.js` script:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.open('test.txt', 'r', function (err, handle) {

    var f = handle;
    var b = new Buffer(100000);

    fs.read(f, b, 0, 100000, null, function (err, bytesRead) {
        console.log(b.toSting("utf8", 0, bytesRead));
        fs.close(f);
    });

});
```

Why do I get the following `TypeError: Bad Argument` error upon running it?

```
$ node fread.js 

fs.js:457
  binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, wrapper);
          ^
TypeError: Bad argument
    at Object.fs.read (fs.js:457:11)
    at /home/max/dev/livelessons/fread.js:8:5
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Comment: @Cerbrus try [checking the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback)

Comment: @Scimonster: Oh, overlooked the function argument, I thought `handle` wasn't set anywhere.

Comment: Duplicating `f` and `handle` variables is unnecessarily btw.

Comment: Argg. So sorry for wasting all of your time. I was opening a non-existent file. `test.txt` should have been `text.txt`. Sure it was a bad argument but that error message gave me little clue as to where to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I gave it the wrong file name. `test.txt` should have been `text.txt`. Doh!

Answer (score 2):

You should check that `fs.open()` was successful first. Most likely `err` is set and `handle` is set to undefined, causing the "Bad Argument" error.